# System32 permissions

Tags: windows-7, windows, security, permissions

I am facing to the problem with System32 folder permissions.

*Example:*

1. If I copy file test.txt into SysWOW64 then I am able to open/read/write it.
2. If I copy same file into System32 then I am not able to open/read/write it.

Both folders have a same permissions.

I have administrators rights, computer is in AD. Windows7 64bit SP1.

I found that if access to System32 via shared folder (\my-computer\c$\Windows\System32) then I am able to open/read/write it.

I am little bit confused and I spent lot of time to solve it.

Thanks for any suggestion,

Michal

Comment: What difference between `icacls C:\Windows\System32\test.txt` and `icacls C:\Windows\SysWOW64\test.txt`?  Also `attrib` and `dir` and `dir /A` using both that arguments?

Comment: icacls - Both are totally same; Yes